# Create tables for multiple entries for each date

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design

I have data sorted by date with multiple entries for each day for the last 22 years (~8000 days). My solution was to create a new table for every date:

Table - 2020-10-23:

| Row1 | Row2 | Row3 | Row4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Text | Text | Text |
| 2 | Text | Text | Text |
| 3 | Text | Text | Text |
| . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . |
| 1000 | Text | Text | Text |

Table - 2020-10-24:

| Row1 | Row2 | Row3 | Row4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Text | Text | Text |
| 2 | Text | Text | Text |
| 3 | Text | Text | Text |
| . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . |
| 1000 | Text | Text | Text |

Like this there would be around 8000 tables and each would have around 800 entries. So around 6 Million entries.

Is this a viable solution (because I need to create more tables for user data, authentication, etc. in the same database)? Is SQLite is the right database for this?

Comment: Definitely not a viable solution. Adding a date column would be better.

Comment: Still there will be 8000 tables in the database. I was thinking of a way to nest tables if that is possible? (I have never worked with this much data, I am not sure whats right and whats wrong)

Comment: There should only be one table. Create a table with the same columns plus an additional date column, write a script to insert all the rows from all these 8000 tables into the new table, then delete all those 8000 tables.

Comment: And definitely use a date data type, not a string that is in date format.  This way when you have a proper index, you can query the data by date ranges without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to create tables for each day. You need to look at what you need to store. Since you have not given any contextual information, I will provide you only general guidelines that you can append to your actual data. If things will be unclear, then you will need to explain what you want to store.

So, as a general rule, whatever is a single value for each entity is considered to be an **attribute**. Whatever is composite, should be considered a separate entity type. You will need to prevent inconsistencies and redundancy by ensuring that your database is in [normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If your data is interrelated and logically describes a single entity for each record, then you will have a single table for now, having a date field and a bunch of other fields as well. If storing everything into a single table is not a feasible approach due to inconsistencies and redundancy, then you will need to break your table down into further tables.

Your pictures suggest that the columns are rows. It's probably a sign of planning errors.

8000 * k (where k on average is less than 1 000) records are not many in the case of modern [RDBMS](https://searchdatamanagement.techtarget.com/definition/RDBMS-relational-database-management-system) tools.

When you `select` records, you can filter/group by the day, achieving the behavior you could have achieved with the different tables you have.

Whether to use or not to use SQLite it is your decision. However, SQLite is a lightweight SQL tool, if you want to go professional, you might want to switch to something else, like MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server or PostgreSQL.